# Unable to compile ios app

Tags: dart, flutter, dart-pub

I am currently trying to test my flutter app on iPhone so I installed intellij, flutter and all other stuff. Everything was going well except that I was unable to build even the demo flutter app on my Mac. In fact, when I run

```
$ flutter create project_name
```

It returns

```
Creating project project_name... Wrote 54 files. 
Running "flutter packages get" in project_name...  
Could not find a file named "pubspec.yaml" in "/Users/user/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dart-lang.org/typed_data-1.1.3". 
pub get failed (1)
```

I can neither run "flutter run" nor "flutter packages get" with the same kind of error, it seem's that the paths to flutter packages are always wrong but when I try in sudo mode I can run all of those commands but I cannot see any device.

Do you have any idea of what I can do to solve this issue ?

Comment: How do you delete .pub-cache directory?

Comment: `pub cache repair` can be used to re-download, but deleting the directory also gets rid of ooutdated versions.

Answer (score 0):

Flutter relies on Dart's Pub package manager to manage dependencies under the hood. Pub maintains a cache of downloaded packages in `~/.pub-cache`. This cache appears to be at least partially corrupted in your case. The pub cache is entirely safe to delete; pub will re-download anything it needs.

The simplest bet is to delete the entire cache via `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache`. It's possible that just that one package is corrupt, in which case, you may be able to get away with selectively deleting just the one (`rm -rf ~/.pub-cache/hosted/pub.dart-lang.org/typed_data-1.1.3`).